# What is best way to add AWS S3 data gets to an existing Android app - AWSJDK, Amplify, or AWS Android JDK without Amplify framework?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a large, old, complex Android app. I need it to now be able to get data from some public S3 buckets.

What is the best way? I have tested the AWSSDK in standalone apps on my Mac and got my code working. But, I don't know if it will work (especially async mode) in Android and if so, how to set up dependencies. Also, is that the best way to go?

Amplify seems to be the Android tool for AWS, but it is focused on full stack development, and requires an AWS account. Can I use it for this even though I have no production use for the account, and my app already exists? Or can I use just its API without installing the Amplify framework and having an account.

Comment: If they are public S3 buckets, why do you need any of those SDKs/tools? Can't you just make basic HTTP GET requests to download the files from the public buckets?

Comment: Mark - thanks - that would be easiest. I don't know what the URL format would be. I have the region info and the bucket name. How do I encode that in a URL?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Mark B above, HTML is one way.

The reference document is [on their site - see below](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/Type_API_Reference.html)